# Regex to read formatted dialogue from play script

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a script for a play in .txt, and am trying to scrape through it to get a list of lines the characters say.  Here is a sample of the layout

```
GARVICK
Not gonna happen. We're here to help, not make things worse!.
(laughs)
This'll be a good one. Hot shot eh, leaves the office to come to the
underworld for some action. What's your problem!

LEON
Those corporate executives are crucial to our operations in this here
underworld. They're gonna get choked. We gotta stop it! I need someone
to get in and out real fast.  And I know you're the guy for the job!  
You gotta be good, I know your style, a little harsh but that's fine!

GARVICK
Tell me more.
```

when I copy this regex into pythex.org:

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+)\n(.+)\n
```

I get the following:

```
Match 1
1.  GARVICK #(this is fine)
2.  Not gonna happen. We're here to help, not make things worse!.
Match 2
1.  leaves the office to come to the
2.  underworld for some action. What's your problem!
Match 3
1.  LEON Those corporate executives are crucial to our operations in this here
2.  underworld. They're gonna get choked. We gotta stop it! I need someone
Match 4
1.  
2.  You gotta be good, I know your style, a little harsh but that's fine!
```

However ideally I believe I would want something like below.  Is there a way to tweak my regex to do this?:

```
Match 1 
1. GARVICK
2. Not gonna happen. We're here to help, not make things worse!.

Match 2
1. GARVICK
2. This'll be a good one.
3. Hot shot eh, leaves the office to come to the underworld for some action. 
4. What's your problem!

Match 3
1. LEON
2. Those corporate executives are crucial to our operations in this here underworld. 
3. They're gonna get choked. 
4. We gotta stop it! 
5. I need someone to get in and out real fast.
6. And I know you're the guy for the job!
7. You gotta be good, I know your style, a little harsh but that's fine!

Match 4
1.  GARVICK
2.  Tell me more.
```

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. You have a fixed list (characters) and can scroll through the text. Regex is incredibly useful in the right circumstance, it also adds significant complexity. You can do this with regular functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is powerful, and incredibly useful when you don't have a (firm) idea of the elements you are working with. Otherwise, it adds significant complexity and, in my opinion, should never be the first tool you reach for.

In this case you have a fixed layout, and a fixed list you want to use to break your text apart.

Example modified to merge together as many of the lines which has been broken across multiple lines. Also included an output for each character, dialogue in individual text files. Requires Python 3.9+ for the walrus operator, if less than 3.9 replace all occurrences of "current_line" with `line.strip()`.

```
# Set up storage variables
actors = ['GARVICK', 'LEON',]
dialogue_collated = []
current_text = []
current_actor = ""

with open('dialogue.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if (current_line:=line.strip()) in actors:
            dialogue_collated.append((current_actor, current_text))
            current_actor = current_line
            current_text = ""
            continue
        # accumulate the current set of dialogue
        if current_line[-1:] in ("!", ".", ")"):
            current_text += line.strip() + "\n"
        else:
            current_text += current_line + " "

# Remove the first empty entry
dialogue_collated.pop(0)

print(dialogue_collated)

for entry in dialogue_collated:
    print(entry[0] + '\n' + entry[1])
    with open(entry[0].replace(' ', '') + '.txt', 'w+') as fo:
        fo.write(entry[1])
```

The output will be a list of tuples, where each tuple represents the current speaker and the current set of dialogue. This is written to each individual text file - the important part is the 'w+', which means if a file exists the text will be appended rather than overwriting the existing file.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful and greatly appreciated and it does seem regex may be overkill at times.  Do you know how, for example, I could print this in a way where, if the comments cross onto another line (like the line "Hot shot eh, leaves the office to come to the\nunderworld for some action.) I could have it consider the text continuous for that block?  So that it wouldn't have the new line between "the" and "underworld" (your example is already very helpful. but at the end of my post I have a little "Match 2, example 3" to get it on the one line.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Depends on what you consider to be a block. I'd probably change the `current_line + "\n"` section to be in an `if` checking if the last character is a punctuation mark and writing a space instead of a newline. But it depends on your definition of a block.

Comment: Let me see here, my ultimate goal is to get each sentence on it's own line in excel (I know how to do the pandas part if I can just get this figured out) so that I can give the actors a list of their lines.  So I suppose, if it could log each sentence after the "NAME", and stop when there's 2 spaces, that might get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Excel! Why? Write each character's dialogue out to a text file and send them the text! Much simpler.

Comment: That's actually a great idea, I just wish the text wasn't spaced midway through each sentence (the short sentences look great, but the long ones get a bit messy breaking halfway, haha).  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Meowsleydale I have added a block merge and text output

Comment: This is amazing!  It's perfect, thank you so much for all your help.  I will be sure to pay it forward, and am so grateful!